# Can I set docker container resource limit to unlimited?

Tags: docker

I understand that we can set docker container resource limit, is it possible to set it as unlimited? so it can use all the resource that the server has.

Answer (score 2):

Docker documentation says:

> By default, a container has no resource constraints and can use as much of a given resource as the host’s kernel scheduler allows.

https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/